# Looking for code improvements for Jackson serialization and deserialization of complex nested structures

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am currently writing a backend in Spring for an extensible, at least somewhat modular, small-scale custom CMS for a gaming community. This requires me to store various information, like installed modules and their configurations or module content, in the database as JSON strings. (NoSQL is unfortunetaly not an option and I was asked to do it in Java, hence my choice of Spring.)

For this to work, I need to be able to store nested Maps of the type <String, Object> inside the database in JSON format. The serialization also is relatively easy, the problem was the deserialization and regularly getting LinkedHashMaps as default fallback from Jackson thrown at me.

So now after I wrote the code to make it all work, I need ideas for improving the performance or, better yet, other and simpler ways of achieving the same thing, since this is a very hacky solution I came up with so far, since I am still a Jackson newb.

In short:
How can I make the following code quicker or use Jackson utilities to make it cleaner and yet still achieve the same?

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ObjectWrapper {
    private String clazz;
    private Object value;
}
```

```java
@Log4j2
public class CustomHashMapJsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<HashMap<String, Object>, String> {

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = getDefaultObjectMapper();

    private static ObjectMapper getDefaultObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        defaultObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return defaultObjectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(HashMap<String, Object> attributeMap) {
        String jsonResult = null;
        ObjectWrapper topLevelWrapper = wrapMapAndContents(attributeMap);
        ObjectWriter objectWriter = objectMapper.writer();
        objectWriter = objectWriter.with(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        try {
            jsonResult = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(objectMapper.valueToTree(topLevelWrapper));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error("Error while serializing a map: ", e);
        }
        return jsonResult;
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Object> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbJsonData) {

        HashMap<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(ObjectWrapper.class, new CustomHashMapJsonDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        try {
            ObjectWrapper topLevelWrapper = objectMapper.readValue(dbJsonData, ObjectWrapper.class);
            resultMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) unwrapObjectWrapperContent(topLevelWrapper);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            log.error("Error while deserializing a retrieved JSON from the DB: ", e);
        }

        return resultMap;
    }

    public ObjectWrapper wrapMapAndContents(Map<String, Object> map) {
        HashMap<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
                resultMap.put(entry.getKey(), wrapMapAndContents((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue()));
            } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof List) {
                resultMap.put(entry.getKey(), wrapListAndContents((List<Object>) entry.getValue()));
            } else {
                resultMap.put(entry.getKey(), wrapObject(entry.getValue()));
            }
        }
        return wrapObject(resultMap);
    }

    public ObjectWrapper wrapListAndContents(List<Object> list) {
        ArrayList<Object> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object listObject : list) {
            if (listObject instanceof Map) {
                resultList.add(wrapMapAndContents((Map<String, Object>) listObject));
            } else if (listObject instanceof List) {
                resultList.add(wrapListAndContents((List<Object>) listObject));
            } else {
                resultList.add(wrapObject(listObject));
            }
        }
        return wrapObject(resultList);
    }

    public ObjectWrapper wrapObject(Object object) {
        return new ObjectWrapper(object.getClass().toString().split(" ")[1], object);
    }

    public Object unwrapObjectWrapperContent(ObjectWrapper topLevelWrapper)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
            InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        Object topLevelObject = Class.forName(topLevelWrapper.getClazz()).cast(topLevelWrapper.getValue());
        if (topLevelObject instanceof Map) {
            Map<String, ObjectWrapper> topLevelMap = (Map<String, ObjectWrapper>) topLevelObject;
            Map<String, Object> newMap = (Map<String, Object>) Class.forName(topLevelWrapper.getClazz())
                    .getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectWrapper> entry : topLevelMap.entrySet()) {
                newMap.put(entry.getKey(), unwrapObjectWrapperContent(entry.getValue()));
            }
            topLevelObject = newMap;
        } else if (topLevelObject instanceof List) {
            List<ObjectWrapper> listOfObjectWrappers = (List<ObjectWrapper>) topLevelObject;
            List<Object> newList = (List<Object>) Class.forName(topLevelWrapper.getClazz())
                    .getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            for (ObjectWrapper objectWrapper : listOfObjectWrappers) {
                newList.add(unwrapObjectWrapperContent(objectWrapper));
            }
            topLevelObject = newList;
        }
        return topLevelObject;
    }
}
```

```java
@Log4j2
public class CustomHashMapJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ObjectWrapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = getDefaultObjectMapper();

    private static ObjectMapper getDefaultObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        defaultObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return defaultObjectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectWrapper deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JacksonException {
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        return convertNode(node);
    }

    private ObjectWrapper convertNode(JsonNode node)
            throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
        ObjectWrapper topLevelWrapper = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.treeAsTokens(node), ObjectWrapper.class);
        try {
            // TODO: Ugly workaround with mapper.treeToValue(mapper.valueToTree(object)) to
            // get back the JsonNode in order to properly deserialize the objects into their
            // respective types
            topLevelWrapper.setValue(objectMapper.treeToValue(objectMapper.valueToTree(topLevelWrapper.getValue()),
                    Class.forName(topLevelWrapper.getClazz())));
            if (topLevelWrapper.getValue() instanceof Map) {
                Map<String, Object> mapObject = (Map<String, Object>) topLevelWrapper.getValue();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : mapObject.entrySet()) {
                    // TODO: Ugly workaround with mapper.valueToTree(object) to get back the
                    // JsonNode in order to properly deserialize the objects into their respective
                    // types
                    mapObject.put(entry.getKey(), convertNode(objectMapper.valueToTree(entry.getValue())));
                }
                topLevelWrapper.setValue(mapObject);
            } else if (topLevelWrapper.getValue() instanceof List) {
                List<Object> listObject = (List<Object>) topLevelWrapper.getValue();
                List<Object> listObjectCopy = (List<Object>) Class.forName(topLevelWrapper.getClazz())
                        .getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
                for (Object objectInList : listObject) {
                    // TODO: Ugly workaround with mapper.valueToTree(object) to get back the
                    // JsonNode in order to properly deserialize the objects into their respective
                    // types
                    listObjectCopy.add(convertNode(objectMapper.valueToTree(objectInList)));
                }
                topLevelWrapper.setValue(listObjectCopy);
                listObject = null;
            }
            // TODO: Too many damn exceptions... Isn't there a way how I can do all this
            // without so many possible Exceptions being thrown?
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException
                | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            log.error("Error while deserializing JSON: ", e);
        }
        return topLevelWrapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question: I am looking for code improvements to improve the performance or simpler ways of achieving what my code achieves. Formulated as a question: "How can I make this code quicker or use utilities of Jackson to make it cleaner?"

Comment: What is your performance requirements? I think your code is logical and orderly and it appears you're doing the best you know how to do.

Comment: I don't really like the fact though that I use mapper.treeToValue(mapper.valueToTree(object)) over and over again. I wonder if there is a better way of only decoding the top level of the JSONNode, while leaving the deeper nested tree intact as JSONNodes that I can pass on to the recursive call.
I feel like this is just too slow considering that I want to store arbitrary JSON content this way and that this deserializer gets called, for example, everytime someone wants to read any news article and for all news articles that I decide to load at the initial page load at that.